# Windows10 - Live Sync files across multiple cloud folders

Tags: windows-10, sync, shared-folders

I'm looking for a solution to sync files from a folder to another on in Windows 10.

The first folder is the one I synchronised from my organisation Sharepoint, and I want to synchronise it with my Adobe Cloud folder.

Is there a windows built in solution for that? Since I cannot install any software on this laptop...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I don't see that this command is really made for live sync, is it?

Comment: Look at the "Repeated Copy Options".

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I managed to create a batch file that loads on system startup! Really helpful.